# Delphi XE4 ios icons

Tags: ios, delphi

Suppose I want to supply my own app icons in deployment (imagine I switch these depending on customer) is there any file name/storage pattern I should follow? Can I set set app icons programmatically or otherwise compile/runtime?

Or do I have to use the Delphi IDE to specify all the icon resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done now is o have a shared folder where my project is configured to get icons from. I then in Window Explorer  simply change icons/backgrounds found in folder. However, this is far from an ideal solution, but I suppose I should mention it as a possible answer.